# according to utilitarianism, can it ever be right to get temporary gain, but long-term loss?

Tags: epistemology, utilitarianism

Throughout life there are many choices: do we eat something fast, or do we cook our own food? Do we skimp (or totally skip) healthcare/ dental coverage, or get regular checkups? Do we hookup with people, or do we have something steady with one person (or a few regulars)? Do we take the job that's physically demanding but pays well or the less demanding job with less pay? Do we cut corners to get a job done or do we work hard and ethically, even if it costs us more in the end?

Each one of these choices is a trade-off. You might get fast food, but it's not healthy. We might save money on our health initially, but then come up with a disease that is severe but manageable, or something incurable (such as certain STDs) and so on.

Even if it works for the majority, is it still *right* due to the consequences that need to be paid later on?

Also, does the fact that we know that these habits are unhealthy play a factor in determining right and wrong? If so, what part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy Bentham's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Bentham) 
"pleasure calculus" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felicific_calculus) 
lists seven elements to consider when making a choice between 
pleasurable or potentially pleasurable activities:

- Intensity: How strong is the pleasure?
- Duration: How long will the pleasure last?
- Certainty or uncertainty: How likely or unlikely is it that the 
  pleasure will occur?
- Propinquity or remoteness: How soon will the pleasure occur?
- Fecundity: The probability that the action will be followed by 
  sensations of the same kind.
- Purity: The probability that it will not be followed by sensations 
  of the opposite kind.
- Extent: How many people will be affected?

If you accept this system, the "propinquity or remoteness" criteria 
suggests that short-term pleasure is more beneficial, whereas the 
"duration" criteria suggests that the long-term pleasure is more 
beneficial. As with any philosophical system, Bentham's calculus 
doesn't tell you which choice to make (you have to weigh the two 
possible criteria yourself), but it does answer your question: if you 
accept Bentham's view of utilitarianism, yes, it's quite possible that 
propinquitous (immediate) pleasure outweighs long-term loss.

Your post strongly suggests that you prefer long-term benefits over 
short-term ones, since you use phrases like "skimp", "cut corners", 
"not healthy", "incurable", "is it still right" (suggesting it's not), 
etc. Here are some balancing thoughts for propinquitous pleasure(in no 
particular order):

- Certainty: while most people agree that fast food, skipping health 
  maintenance appointments and casual sex are "bad for you" and reduce 
  your life expectancy, this is a vague and undefined risk. There's no 
  guarentee that any of things will give you displeasure in the future 
  and there are things you can do (eg, safe sex) to make future 
  displeasure even less certain.
- Intensity: the benefits of cooking your own food, health 
  maintenance, avoid sexual disease, and perfectionism are fairly 
  mild. Living a long and healthy life is nice, but that kind of 
  pleasure is passive and not intense. Perfectionism for the sake of 
  perfectionism may give you pleasure in knowing you did the job 
  "right", but this, again, seems like minor self-satisfaction, not 
  intense pleasure. In this case, I'd say it's a tie.
- Intensity: Sexual pleasure is intense, even when repeated, but the 
  intensity of avoiding sexual disease is very low, as above.
- Fecundity: casual sex probably will lead to more casual sex as you 
  build up a group of casual sex partners.
- Purity: perfectionism may give you some pleasure, but 
  perfectionism is often annoying to coworkers and employers, because 
  perfectionists often inefficiently spend too much time working on a 
  single project, focus too much on a small detail, don't accept help 
  from others, or even come up with rigid designs that are hard to 
  change in the future. Perfectionism is an impure pleasure because it 
  leads to things that may cause you displeasure.

You note "even if it works for the majority", but I don't think that's 
an argument to "extent", and seems a little out of place. 
Utilitarianism deems something "right" if it works, almost by 
definition. Therefore, if something works for the majority, 
utilitarianism says it's "right" for the majority, which would seem to 
work against your arugment that it's not "right" under 
utilitarianism. However, I don't think what the majority does affects 
your decisions that much, nor vice versa, so it seems irrelevant.

In conclusion, I'd say you can make a strong argument that immediate 
pleasure can outweigh long-term benefits under the doctorine of 
utilitarianism, even though your question appears to be biased against 
that position.